# What is and what represents a convergents function in polynomial form?

Tags: trigonometry, numerical-linear-algebra

[$$\mathbf{convergents}(cos(1), 20)$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20%20polynomial%20Convergents%28cos%281%29%2C%2020%29)

What exactly is a *convergents function* and what, that series of fractions is representing ? There is an use for this in numerical linear algebra ?

Feel free to replace the pair function & value from $cos(1)$ if you need to to explain this .

Answer (score 1):

Your call produced the first 20 convergents of the (irrational) number $\cos 1$, i.e. rational approximations to it obtained by the theory of continued fractions. Trivia: If you try the golden ration instead of $\cos 1$, you may notice that Fibonacci numbers occur as numerators and denominators.

Comment: what algorithm gives you this while adopting a numerical ( computable ) approach ?

Comment: it looks more like a prime number generator than something usable for trigonometry or numerical linear algebra: what's the practical use for this ?

Comment: @user2485710 In a way the convergents are the *best* possible rationl approximations. It's no surprise that the well-known approximations $3$ and $\frac{22}7$ are emitted as the first convergents for $\pi$, for example

Comment: yes, it's rational and it's an approximation, but it's not "interesting" for computation, there isn't something like a continued fraction but with a variable, with my $x$ ? AFAIK I can use this to store an approximation for $\pi$, for example, in C `const double PI = pickAFraction` but it's not something usable to compute, let's say, the cosine in a fractional way with $x$ variable .